# How to mock inherited methods

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Im trying to mock a method that is ineherited from a parent class that is generic. Right know my code looks like this.

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> FindMany(Func<T, bool> condition);
}

public interface IPersonRepository : IBaseRepository<person>
{
    //Here I got some specifics methods for person repository
}
```

My test code looks like this;

```
    private IPersonRepository mockPersonRepository { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMehtod()
    {
        LogonModel model = CreateLogonModel("test@test.com", "test", "Index");
        person p = new person() { Email = model.Email, password = model.Password, PersonId = 1 };

        mockPersonRepository.Stub(x => x.FindMany(y => y.Email == model.Email && y.password == model.Password)).Return(new List<person> {p});
        mockPersonRepository.Replay();

        var actual = instanceToTest.LogOnPosted(model) as PartialViewResult;

        Assert.AreEqual("_Login", actual.ViewName);
    }
```

When I am using the debugging tool in vs 2010 I can se that me Stub, doesnt works, the return person is always null. I have declared the FindMany method as virtual.

Does anybody know how to stub that method? Im using RhinoMocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the lambda - but you are really interested in having *the `person` instance passed into the lambda* match your `person` object based on satisfying the predicate condition - You can use `Matches()` to achieve this by just executing the predicate on `p` - if that equates to `true` than you have a match and should return the stubbed list:

```
mockPersonRepository.Stub(x => x.FindMany(Arg<Func<person, bool>>.Matches( y => y(p))))
                    .Return(new List<person> { p });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it really helped me! Now i want to test that i really uses the model i pass to the method LogonPosted. How can I do that? I have been trying to do that like:

mockPersonRepository.Expect(x => x.FindMany( Arg<Func<person, bool>>.Matches( y => y(p)))).Return();

But if I set up my test like that it always gets green. How do I expect the that Im really calling the personRepository with the data from the model.